# Is it possible to set breakpoint at OpenGL functions?

Tags: debugging, opengl, gdb, breakpoints

Sometimes I need to find out which part of the code call a certain OpenGL function, so I try this:

```
b glEnableVertexAttribArray
----------------------------
Breakpoint 3 at 0x7ffff0326c80 (2 locations)
```

But it doesn't work, is there any way to make this work?

I'm using `gdb` in `ubuntu18.04`, my GPU is `GeForce GTX 1050 Ti`

Comment: Does your program use an OpenGL loader like GLAD or GLEW by any chance?

Comment: @Botje I have tried GLAD c-debug generator, it works nicely. How to do it with GLEW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your `GL/glew.h` header, you will see that it contains lines similar to the following:

```
#define GLEW_GET_FUN(x) x
#define glCopyTexSubImage3D GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewCopyTexSubImage3D)
#define glDrawRangeElements GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewDrawRangeElements)
#define glTexImage3D GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewTexImage3D)
#define glTexSubImage3D GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewTexSubImage3D)
```

When you call `glewInit`, these `__glew*` variables are populated with pointers extracted from your OpenGL implementation.
In your case, you should set a breakpoint on the contents of such a pointer, so `*__glewEnableVertexAttribArray`.

For GLAD you will have to put a breakpoint on `*glad_glEnableVertexAttribArray`. Note the `*` in both cases: that tells your debugger to dereference the pointer and put the breakpoint at the correct location.

Comment: The same approach doesn't work on `GLAD`, gdb doesn't let me set breakpoint on functions populated with OpenGL implementation, I can only set breakpont on `glad_debug_impl_*`, which is real function that calls populated function. I havn't try it with glew, it looks suspicious, I will try it later.

Comment: Can't you put a breakpoint on `*glad_glEnableVertexAttribArray` after GLAD has loaded all the pointers? (note the *)